# How the Callback() really works ?How to insert multiple collections in mongodb using callbacks.?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am new to node, I am trying to insert multiple collection.I have tried below code seeing some examples and its workng fine

```
function createUser(admindata, callback) {
    admindata.save(callback);
}

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    const admindata = new Note({
        fname: req.body.fname,
        lname: req.body.lname || "Untitled Note",
        age: req.body.age,

    })

    createUser(admindata, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        lastInsertId = result._id;
        if (lastInsertId) {
            const usersData = new Address({
                user_address_id: lastInsertId,
                pincode: req.body.pin,
                city: req.body.city,
                state: req.body.state
            })
            createUser(usersData, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.send(result);
            });
        }

    });

}
```

What I really want is there any better ways to make this happen using `callback functions` and what exaclty the `callback()` function and how to use it and when to use it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback is a function that is to be executed after another function has finished executing.

In `JavaScript` functions are `objects` so you can pass any function as a parameter to other functions that's why callbacks were use extensively in javascipt.

In your code in the create user function you take function as parameter as you can see.

`createUser(admindata,callback)`  here ***callback*** is a function as a parameter.
Then inside the function you are passing that function (*callback*) to `save` method which also takes a function as a parameter (*callback* function).

The **2nd** call of the **createUser** function is in callback of **save method** therefore it will execute after the completion of first **createUser**.

In the 2nd call instead of declaring a function you are passing an **anonymous function** as parameter which will be executed after the execution of 2nd call.

Example - Using anonymous function as callback

```
createUser(data,function(err,data){
    if(err) 
    {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

Example using normal function as callback

```
function exampleFunction(err,data){ 
    if(err) 
    {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
//passing normal function
createUser(data,exampleFunction) ;
```

Comment: instead of **anonymous function** which function that I need pass and How.?

Comment: Using anonymous function is perfectly fine. You can also use normal function just buy specifying its name instead of defining an anonymous function. I will add example in the answer

Comment: Sorry sir, I am not able give response for your answer, Know I got an idea about how`callback` function works, thank you for time.